# Datepicker in angular shown at bottom

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2

I am facing an issue with datepicker I am using for angular2. I tried the code from https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples. The output shown in this site is what I need, but instead I am getting the calendar shown at the bottom of the page after footer. There are no CSS changes given in the example.

I am using the following code.

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
 <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
 <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
 <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-overview-example.css'],
})
export class DatepickerOverviewExample {}
```

Screenshots :
[Output I need (from example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfYhZ.png)

[Output I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11d8Y.png)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the theming for your app. There should also be a warning in the console that no default theme was found.

Add the following line to your global stylesheet file (most likely `styles.css`):

```css
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

Alternatively:

```html
<head>
    <!-- Content goes here -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css">
    <!-- More content goes here -->
</head>
```